# ¿Cómo lograr que se inserten números de forma automática en una cola de lenguaje c?

Tags: c, estructuras-de-datos

tengo mi código completamente funcional de una estructura de datos de cola, sin embargo quiero realizarle una modificación, en mi código se le pide al usuario que ingrese los números para agregar a la cola y lo que quiero es que estos sean agregados de manera automática, es decir que no se pidan los números al usuario.

En si cuando seleccione la opción de encolar quiero que se añadan los números (que en mi caso el limite es de cuatro números) de manera sucesiva

que se muestre algo así básicamente:

```
Escoja una opción: 1

insertar

1->2->3->4
```

y que cuando se desencole siga la sucesión numérico ósea que si tengo 3->4 al volver a seleccionar la opción de encolar ponga 3->4->5->6

Gracias de antemano.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct lista {
    int clave;
    struct lista * sig;
};

struct lista * inicio = NULL;
struct lista * nuevo;
struct lista * aux;
struct lista * anterior;
struct lista * ultimo;
int contador;

void insertar();
void desapilar();

int main() {
    int opcionMenu = 0;
    do {

        printf("\n\n|               cola         ");

        printf("\n| 1. Encolar");
        printf("\n| 2. Desencolar");
        printf("\n| 3. Salir");
        printf("\n\n Escoja una Opcion: ");
        scanf("%d", & opcionMenu);
        switch (opcionMenu) {
        case 1:
            printf("\n\n INSERTAR  \n\n");
            insertar();
            break;
        case 2:
            desapilar();
            break;
        case 3:
            printf("\n\n Programa finalizado...");
            break;
        default:
            printf("\n\n Opcion No Valida \n\n");
        }
    } while (opcionMenu != 3);
    return 0;
}

void insertar()
{
    while (contador < 4) {

        nuevo = (struct lista * ) malloc(sizeof(struct lista));
        printf(" Ingrese un dato: ");
        scanf("%d", & nuevo -> clave);

        if (inicio == NULL) {

            inicio = nuevo;
            inicio -> sig = NULL;
            ultimo = nuevo;
            contador++;
        } else {
            ultimo -> sig = nuevo;
            nuevo -> sig = NULL;
            ultimo = nuevo;
            contador++;
        }
    }

    {

        aux = (struct lista * ) malloc(sizeof(struct lista));
        aux = inicio;
        if (inicio != NULL) {
            while (aux != NULL) {
                printf("%d->", aux -> clave);
                aux = aux -> sig;
            }
        } else {
            printf("\n La cola se encuentra Vacia\n\n");
        }
    }
}

void desapilar() {
    nuevo = (struct lista * ) malloc(sizeof(struct lista));
    printf(" Dato Desencolado: ");

    if (inicio != NULL) {
        aux = inicio;
        inicio = inicio -> sig;

        free(aux);
        contador--;
    }

    {

        aux = (struct lista * ) malloc(sizeof(struct lista));
        aux = inicio;
        if (inicio != NULL) {
            while (aux != NULL) {
                printf("%d->", aux -> clave);
                aux = aux -> sig;
            }
        } else {
            printf("\n La pila se encuentra Vacia\n\n");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: En lugar de un `scanf` usa una variable a la que le incrementas el valor.

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!